# In InputStream, what does blocksize do? (sounddevice)

Tags: python, callback, python-sounddevice

I am building a guitar tuner GUI with sounddevice. This is my code for the recording part:

```py
 def stream(self):
        if self.stream is not None:
            self.stream.close()
        self.stream = sd.InputStream(
          channels=1, callback=self.callback, blocksize=...) 
        self.stream.start()
```

This is callback:

```py
# tunertools is another file with functions that compute on arrays
def callback(indata, frames, time, status):
        print(indata)
        data = indata.copy()
        yin , *others = tunertools.YIN(data, frames)
        pitch = tunertools.avg_pitch(yin)
        noteslist = {k:v for k,v in tunertools.notes()}
        note = tunertootls.quantize(pitch, noteslist.values)
        print( {v:k for (k,v) in noteslist.values()}[note] )
```

For now, I am printing the output in terminal. I want a new output to be printed every 4 seconds of recording. This means that every 4 seconds, the callback function should be initiated. How do I do this? More importantly, do I need to use the blocksize parameter to do this?

Comment: The callback function is called at a rate determined by `blocksize`. If you make `blocksize` larger, the callback will be called less often. If you want to obtain information at a different rate than the callback is called, you can have a look at the example [plot_input.py](https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/blob/master/examples/plot_input.py) which uses a separate function for obtaining information and a `queue.Queue` for communications between them.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Post this as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback function is called at a rate determined by `blocksize`. If you make `blocksize` larger, the callback will be called less often.

If you want to obtain information at a different rate than the callback is called, you can have a look at the example [plot_input.py](https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/blob/master/examples/plot_input.py) which uses a separate function for obtaining information and a `queue.Queue` for communications between them.

If you just want some code to be executed every, say, third time the callback is called, you can simply use a global counter variable and check and increment it in the callback.